# How to understand spark api for elasticsearch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I came across [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html) page, which has this code line :

```
JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, "spark/docs");
```

I am trying to understand what is the second argument `spark/docs` here. After googling, I came across [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/spark/core/main/scala/org/elasticsearch/spark/rdd/api/java/JavaEsSpark.scala) page on github. It says:

```
def saveToEs(jrdd: JavaRDD[_], resource: String) = EsSpark.saveToEs(jrdd.rdd, resource)
```

It seems that `spark/docs` is a `resource`. As far as I understand, resource means actual document to be indexed. But then how is it a document? Is it an index name to which the document should be added? I am struggling mainly because I did not find official documentation of the elasticsearch spark api, am new to elasticsearch and also I am not good at scala.

Comment: I know i might be sounding stupid for this question. But will love to know why, instead of passive down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects in the below code:

```
JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, "spark/docs");
```

The above code writes a data into the Elasticsearch. The two arguments are:

**javaRDD** - This would be nothing but an immutable list of elements or in Spark word an `RDD` which you want to ingest into elasticsearch.

In Java world, they are `immutable serialized objects`. In Elasticsearch world, they would be `documents`.

**spark/docs** - This would be the ***sink*** in which you want to ingest the data. In other words, it is `index` in which your documents (or in Spark world **RDD**) would be ingested.

In short it is `index name` followed by the `type name` in elasticsearch. ES since version 7.x has removed customized type name. Therefore, in order to ingest into any other index in Elasticsearch you can simply specify `you_own_index_name/docs`

So basically the code `JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, "spark/docs");` simply writes or ingests data that is there in `javaRDD` into Elasticsearch's index `spark`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yess this is my intuition, but then github confused me by naming second argument `resource`. Is index also called as resource in elasticsearch spark terminology? Also is their any java doc like documentation for the elasticsearch spark API?

Comment: Unfortunately nope. You would have to peruse through their source code to understand more on the API. However I believe you would find plenty of resources in SOF as well as on other internet to get more on spark ES API examples. Most of the code is in Scala but OTOH, you get to learn/read Scala.

Comment: thanks, thats answer to second question in my comment. Can you please answer first (starting two sentences in my last comment)?

Comment: hey @anir, apologies. `Index` is a resource as that is where the documents would be stored in `elasticsearch` while spark is analytical processing tool. In a nutshell, you can metaphorically compare index in ESt with table in RDBMS/database. Does that help?

Comment: relational databases contain tables, similarly ES index contains documents, though this sounds weird. Saying index "contains" documents sounds confusing as we usually say index records, at least in relational databases. The same is the case with ES. Index does indeed index documents, but they also contain documents. Please correct me if I am wrong in above sentences.